# Get list of two numbers that add up to a number in prolog

Tags: prolog, sum

for example, getNumbers(M,C,10) would give M=10, C = 0 && M=9, C=1 && M=8, C=2... etc etc

Comment: I feel like I should be using between() somehow in this...

Comment: BTW - it's better to edit the question with these sorts of comments than to leave a comment on your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using between as you suggested:

```
getNumbers(M, C, S):-
  between(0, S, M),
  C is S - M.
```

and to get the full list you would use `findall/3`, e.g. this query:

```
?- findall([M,C], getNumbers(M, C, 5), Numbers).
Numbers = [[0, 5], [1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1], [5, 0]].
```